# How to show that this mapping is linear?

Tags: linear-algebra

> For an n-dimensional vector space $V$ and an ordered basis $B$ of $V$
>   , the mapping $\Phi : \mathbb{R}^n → V , \Phi(e_i) = b_i, i = 1,...,n$
>   is linear , where $E = (e_1,...,e_n)$ is the standard basis of
>   $\mathbb{R}^n$.

This is a paragraph from my textbook, I am trying to figure out why $\Phi$ is a linear map.

For an example, If I set $n=2$, I can show that there exist a linear combination of $B$ vectors for each vector of $E$ where in this case $E = (e_1, e_2)$ (Cartesian basis) and $B = \{(1, -1)^T, (1, 1)^T\}$. But I don't know what to do after this.

Accroding to my book, the mapping is also isomorphic since  $\Phi$ is linear and $\dim(\mathbb{R}^n) = \dim(V)$, I am just stuck at seeing the linearity part. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, vector spaces are defined in an absolutely abstract way. Namely, a vector space $V$ over a field $\Bbb K$ is just a set on which are defined two operations (inner operation and an external operation) that satisfy a precise list of axioms.

When $\Bbb K=\Bbb R$, the set $\Bbb R^n$ is the simplest example possible. What is nice is that any abstract vector space $V$ of dimension $n$ over $\Bbb R$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb R^n$.

The correct way to define $\Phi$ is the following. Fix a basis, usually the Cartesian basis $\{e_1,\dots, e_n\}$ for $\Bbb R^n$ and a basis $\{b_1,\dots,b_n\}$ for $V$. Define $\Phi:\Bbb R^n\to V$ in this way:

1. Pick $(a_1,\dots,a_n)\in \Bbb R^n$,
2. Let $w=a_1e_1+\cdots + a_ne_n$
3. Define $\Phi(w)=v\in V$ as $a_1b_1+\cdots +a_nb_n$.

Now verify that $\Phi$ is linear, injective and surjective.

Final notice: This construction holds for any field $\Bbb K$. I used $\Bbb R$ since your question is posed when $\Bbb K=\Bbb R$.

Comment: Of course this is what the text book ought to have said!

Comment: Yes, exactly. This is the right way to define $\Phi$.

Comment: @InsideOut are you sure point no. 3 isn't missing a $w$?

Comment: @Algo sure! Thanks.

Comment: @InsideOut Thanks for the clarification, regarding point no. 3 you're basically defining $\Phi$ as a linear combination of vector space $V$ basis using the same coefficients $(a_1,...,a_n)$?

Comment: Yes, after you have fixed a basis on the source, say $B_1$, and on the target, say $B_2$, the image of a vector $w$ is the vector $v\in V$ whose coefficients wrt $B_2$ are the same of $w$ wrt $B_1$.

Answer (score 0):

As stated this is false unless all the $b_i=0$ . Let $\Phi$ be as stated on the $e_i$ and let $\Phi(x)=0$ otherwise.

Then $\Phi(2e_i)=0$ but $2\Phi(e_i)=2 b_i$ so for linearity we need $b_i=0$.

Comment: Can you please clarify more?